# Swift async/await what it the replacement of DispatchQueue.main.async

Tags: swift, async-await

How I can return to main thread when using async/await concurrency mechanism in new Swift 5.5? Should I just mark function, class with @MainActor.
Can I still use `DispatchQueue.main.async`? Will it be correct? As new mechanism doesn't use GCD and there is no mapping between async tasks and thread like before?

For example I am using SwiftUI `List` with `refreshable`

```
List { }
.refreshable {
    viewModel.fetchData()
}
```

Is this ok

```
List { }
.refreshable {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      viewModel.fetchData()
    }
}
```

Or I need to add @MainActor on ViewModel class?
I doesn't use async/await in project so using MainActor just for this single refreshable seems redundant, I also doesn't know how adding such attribute influance remaining methods and properties of ViewModel class, they now use Combine.

But on the other hand Xcode displays

> runtime: SwiftUI: Publishing changes from background threads is not
> allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via
> operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.

Moreover after adding @MainActor to ViewModel I am getting multiple warnings like this

> Property 'title' isolated to global actor 'MainActor' can not satisfy
> corresponding requirement from protocol
> 'OnlineBankingListViewModelProtocol'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You asked:

> Can I still use `DispatchQueue.main.async`?

If you are in an `async` method and want to dispatch something to the main queue, the most literal equivalent would be:

```swift
MainActor.run { ... }
```

But it is more prudent to simply mark the method (or its class) with `@MainActor`. Not only will this ensure that it runs it on the main thread, but you get compile-time warnings if you attempt to call it from the wrong actor.

So, if your view model is marked with `@MainActor`, the manual running of the task on the `MainActor` becomes unnecessary. This is especially true when dealing with published properties of an observed object.

For example, consider:

```swift
@MainActor
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var values: [Int] = []

    func fetchData() async {
        let foo = await ...
        values = foo.values
    }
}
```

And then

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ...
        }
        .refreshable {
            await viewModel.fetchData()
        }

    }
}
```

(Note, I made `fetchData` an `async` method and `await` it within `refreshable` so that the spinner accurately reflects when the `async` process is running.)

See WWDC 2021 video [Swift concurrency: Update a sample app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10194/). That is admittedly illustrating the transition of a UIKit app, but includes examples of `@MainActor` and `MainActor.run`.

---

Note, while `@MainActor`, largely eliminates the need for `MainActor.run { … }`, there are still some scenarios where you might use this `run` pattern. Specifically, if you are on some other actor and want to run, for example, three separate `@MainActor` functions in succession on the main thread, you can wrap the series of them within a single `MainActor.run { … }` block, thereby running all three with a single dispatch to the main actor, rather than three separate calls.

---

Above, I focused on the salient portions, but here is my full MCVE:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.values, id: \.self) { value in
                Text("\(value)")
            }
        }
        .refreshable {
            await viewModel.fetchData()
        }

    }
}

struct Foo: Decodable{
    let json: [Int]
}

@MainActor
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var values: [Int] = []

    func fetchData() async {
        do {
            let foo = try await object(Foo.self, for: request)
            values = foo.json
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func object<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, for request: URLRequest) async throws -> T {
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)

        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
            throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
        }

        guard 200 ... 299 ~= response.statusCode else {
            throw ApiError.failure(response.statusCode, data)
        }

        return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
    }

    var request: URLRequest = {
        let url = URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/anything")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = "[1,2,3,4,5]".data(using: .utf8)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        return request
    }()
}

enum ApiError: Error {
    case failure(Int, Data)
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Not only describes exactly what OP asked but also provides additional best practices for compile-time checks.

Answer (score 9):

The replacement for `DispatchQueue.main.async { foo.bar() }` is:

```
Task { @MainActor in 
    print(Thread.current.isMainThread) // "true"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a lot of cases, the new async model will work out what thread is best suited to execute a task, if your task has access to Guide objects, the compiler/runtime will choose to run the entire task in the main thread, if you have other things you want to run in the main thread, you can use @ MainActor, but the more stuff you force in the main thread, the more work you will put on that thread and the less work will be given to other threads, and so less chance for your work to be spread across multiple cores. If you really push it you can get a task to run in the background thread that access Guide stuff, and you will find execution will jump to the main thread to execute the GUI call. If there are a set of calls you want to run in the main thread with some gui code you code just wrap them in a task, and the the runtime system sort it our for you.