# How to run async await on main thread

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency

Please find the code:

```
Task{
  let value = await doSomething()
}
```

I tried using DispatchQueue, but how to guarantee if UI updates should be done on main thread.

```
Task{
 DispatchQueue.main.async{
  let value = await doSomething()
 }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift async/await what it the replacement of DispatchQueue.main.async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71076693/swift-async-await-what-it-the-replacement-of-dispatchqueue-main-async)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use @MainActor for running the code on main thread.

```
Task{ @MainActor in 
 let value = await doSomething()
}
```

or you can directly mark the function to run on main thread.

```
@MainActor func myFunc() {
 Task{ 
  let value = await doSomething()
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `await MainActor.run` :

```
Task {
    // Background thread
    
    await MainActor.run {
        // Main thread
    }
}
```